# codeigniter basic mysql form

Tags: mysql, forms, codeigniter

can anyone point me to the right direction?
I found a tutorial for codeigniter that displays sql results in a table, something like this:

```
    public function results() {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM fuel"
    . "ORDER BY date DESC");        
    return $this->table->generate($query);
    }
```

that works perfectly!
But now i'm searching a tutorial that explains add a edit and a delete button, so I can update a record and delete a record (and how to add a record)

i found this: [Update data CI](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#update)
where do I put this code? in the model, view or controler?
and how do I get these update a delete links in my table each row?

I've searched the tuts from CI and they explained what a form helpeer is and a mysql helper, table helper that helps but the thing that helps me the most is a working script that has this all ready and working.

can someone point met to a good tutorial of show a working script?

the tutorials I found explained how to create a form without mysql

Comment: Any query to `fetch` or `update` records you need to write in `model`. This one is a good tutorial on `CI`. http://p2p.wrox.com/book-professional-codeigniter-isbn-978-0-470-28245-8-414/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have write a general model as for my personal use in CodeIgniter Structure .. 
I have covered possible all methods which is need to use for data manipulation.

copy following code in paste in **general_model.php inside your model directory**...

```
class General_model extends CI_Model
{
private $_table;
private $_fields;
public $fields;

function __construct()
{
    // Call the Model constructor
    parent::__construct();
}

/**
 * Set table name
 * @access public
 * @param  string - sets table_name
 * @return null
 * @author Rajnish Savaliya
 */
function set_table($table_name)
{
    $this->_table = $table_name;
    $this->_fields = $this->db->list_fields($this->_table);
    foreach($this->_fields as $field) {
        $this->fields[$field] = "";
    }
}

/**
 * Get record from tables
 * @access public
 * @return array()
 * @author Rajnish Savaliya
 */
function get_fields_array()
{
    return $this->_fields;
}

/**
 * Get record from table
 * @access public
 * @param number - sets limit
 * @param number - sets offset
 * @param array  - sets order
 * @author Rajnish Savaliya
 * @return array()
 */
function get($select = array(),$conditions = array(),$order=array(),$limit=NULL,$offset=NULL)
{
    $this->db->select($select)->from($this->_table)->where($conditions);
    if($order)
    $this->db->order_by(key($order),$order[key($order)]);
    if($limit && $offset)
    $this->db->limit($limit,$offset);
    elseif($limit)
        $this->db->limit($limit);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}

/**
 * GET [copy] Get record from table
 * @access public
 * @param number - sets limit
 * @param number - sets offset
 * @param array  - sets order
 * @author Rajnish Savaliya
 * @return stdClass()
 */
function get_stdClass($select = array(),$conditions = array(),$order=array(),$limit=NULL,$offset=NULL)
{
    $this->db->select($select)->from($this->_table)->where($conditions);
    if($order)
    $this->db->order_by(key($order),$order[key($order)]);
    if($limit && $offset)
    $this->db->limit($limit,$offset);
    elseif($limit)
        $this->db->limit($limit);

    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}

/**
 * Advance Get Function
 * @access public
 * @param number - select values
 * @param number - sets limit
 * @param number - sets offset
 * @param array  - sets order
 * @param array  - sets groupby
 * @author Rajnish Savaliya
 * @return array()
 */
function advance_get($select = array(),$conditions = array(),$order=array(),$groupby='',$limit=NULL,$offset=NULL)
{
    $this->db->select($select)->from($this->_table)->where($conditions);
    if($order)
    $this->db->order_by(key($order),$order[key($order)]);

    if($groupby != ''){
     $this->db->group_by($groupby);
    }

    $this->db->limit($limit,$offset);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}


/**
 * Get record by id from table
 * @access public
 * @param number - sets limit
 * @param number - sets offset
 * @param array  - sets order
 * @author Rajnish Savaliya
 * @return array()
 */

function get_by_id($id,$order=array("id"=>"ASC"),$limit='1',$offset=NULL)
{
    $this->db->where("id",$id);
    $this->db->from($this->_table)->order_by(key($order),$order[key($order)])->limit($limit,$offset);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}

/**
 * Save record in table
 * @access public
 * @param array  -
 * @return insert id
 * @author Rajnish Savaliya
 */
function save($data,$password = NULL,$created = NULL)
{
    if(!empty($data))
    {
        //if password field exist then
        if($password != NULL)
        {
            $data[$password] = md5($data[$password]);
        }
        if($created != NULL)
        {
            $data[$created] =  date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        }

        $data = elements($this->_fields,$data);
        $this->db->insert($this->_table, $data);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Save batch record in table
 * @access public
 * @param array  - all combine data
 * @return insert id
 * @author Rajnish Savaliya
 */
public function saveBatch($collection){
    $this->db->insert_batch($this->_table, $collection);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}

/**
 * Update record in table
 * @access public
 * @param array  - task data
 * @param array  - field name & value
 * @return boolean
 *  @author Rajnish Savaliya
 */
function update($data,$fieldValue = array())
{
    if(!empty($data) && !empty($fieldValue))
    {
        $this->db->where($fieldValue);
        $this->db->update($this->_table,$data);

        if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0)
        return true;
        else
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Delete record in table
 * @access public
 * @param array  - field name & value
 * @return boolean
 *  @author Rajnish Savaliya
 */

function delete($fieldValue = array())
{
    if(!empty($fieldValue))
    {
        $this->db->delete($this->_table,$fieldValue);
        if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0)
        return true;
        else
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Delete record in table
 * @access public
 * @param array  - field name & value
 * @return boolean
 *  @author Rajnish Savaliya
 */

function delete_multiple($where_in = array(), $fieldName)
{
    if(!empty($where_in))
    {
        $this->db->where_in($fieldName,$where_in);
        $this->db->delete($this->_table);
        if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0)
        return true;
        else
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Delete record in table
 * @access public
 * @param array  - field name & value
 * @return boolean
 *  @author Rajnish Savaliya
 */
function update_multiple($data,$where_in = array(), $fieldName)
{
    if(!empty($where_in))
    {
        $this->db->where_in($fieldName,$where_in);
        $this->db->update($this->_table,$data);
        if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0)
        return true;
        else
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Get Field or Fields By Id
 * @access public
 * @param  string  - field name
 * @param  number  - field id
 * @return boolean
 *  @author Rajnish Savaliya
 */

function get_fields($field_names = NULL , $id = NULL)
{
    if($field_names != NULL && $id != NULL)
    {
        $this->db->select($field_names)->from($this->_table)->where('id',$id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $record = $query->result_array();
        if(!empty($record))
        {
            if(count(explode(",", $field_names)) > 1)
            return $record[0];
            else
            return $record[0][$field_names];
        }
        return "";
    }
    return "";
}

/**
 * Join Two Table
 * @access public
 * @param array  - result
 * @return stdClass
 *  @author Rajnish Savaliya
 */
public function singleJoin($parentTable,$childTable,$select,$condition,$where=array()){
    $this->db->select($select);
    $this->db->from($parentTable);
    $this->db->where($where);
    $this->db->join($childTable,$condition);
    return $this->db->get()->result_array();
}


/**
 * Join Two or More Table : mulitple joins with multiple where condition and multiple like condition
 * @access public
 * @param array  - result
 * @return stdClass   - result
 * @author Rajnish Savaliya
 */

public function multijoins($fields,$from,$joins,$where,$ordersby='',$action=NULL,$likes=NULL,$num=NULL,$offset=NULL,$wheretype='where',$groupby=''){

    $this->db->select($fields);
    if($wheretype == 'where'){
        $this->db->where($where);
    }
    if($wheretype == 'where_in'){
        $this->db->where($where);
    }
    if($groupby != ''){
     $this->db->group_by($groupby);
    }
    foreach($joins as $key => $value){
        $this->db->join($key, $value[0], $value[1]);
    }
    if($likes != NULL){
        foreach($likes as $field =>$like){
            $this->db->like($field, $like);
        }
    }
    if($ordersby != ''){
        $this->db->order_by(''.$ordersby.'');
    }
    if($action == 'count'){
        return  $this->db->get($from)->num_rows();
    }
    elseif($action == 'array'){
        return $this->db->get($from,$num,$offset)->result_array();
    }

    else{
        return $this->db->get($from,$num,$offset)->result();
    }
}

/**
 * Join Two or More Table : mulitple joins with multiple where condition and multiple like condition
 * @access public
 * @param array  - result
 * @return ArrayObject  - result
 * @author Rajnish Savaliya
 */
public function multijoins_arr($fields,$from,$joins,$where,$custom_where=NULL,$ordersby='',$num=NULL,$offset=NULL,$action='',$wheretype='where',$groupby=''){
    $this->db->select($fields);
    if($wheretype == 'where'){
        $this->db->where($where);
    }
    if($wheretype == 'where_in'){
        /*$field =  implode(",",(array_keys($where)));
      $this->db->where_in(''.$field.'', $where['p.products_id']);*/
        $this->db->where($where);
    }
    if($groupby != ''){
     $this->db->group_by($groupby);
    }
    foreach($joins as $key => $value){
        $this->db->join($key, $value[0], $value[1]);
    }
    if($custom_where != NULL){
        $this->db->where($custom_where);
    }
    if($ordersby != ''){
        $this->db->order_by(''.$ordersby.'');
    }
    if($action == 'count'){
        return  $this->db->get($from,$num,$offset)->num_rows();
    }else{
        return $this->db->get($from,$num,$offset)->result_array();
    }
}

/**
 * Function give next/ successor id from calculating ids.
 * @access public
 * @param array  - result
 * @return id
 * @author Rajnish Savaliya
 */
public function getNextId($tableName,$id='id',$alias='')
{
    if($alias == '')
    {
        $alias = $id;
    }

    $this->db->select_max($id,$alias);
    $query = $this->db->get($tableName);
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result['0'][$alias]+1;
}

/**
 * Function check record is exist or not.
 * @access public
 * @param array  - result
 * @return boolean true if have dublicate record and false doen't dublicate record
 * @author Rajnish Savaliya
 */
public function checkDuplicate($condition,$table=''){
    if($table == '')
    $table = $this->_table;

    $query = $this->db->get_where($table,$condition);
    if($query->num_rows()>=1){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Count Number of record from table
 * @access public
 * @Optional = table name
 * @author Rajnish Savaliya
 * @return array()
 */
function count_record($condition,$table='')
{
    if($table == '')
    $table = $this->_table;

    $query = $this->db->get_where($table,$condition);
    return $query->num_rows();
}

/**
 * Count Number of record from table
 * @access public
 * @Optional = table name
 * @author Rajnish Savaliya
 * @return array()
 */
function custom_get($select,$condition = '')
{
    $sql = "SELECT ".$select." FROM ".$this->_table;
    if($condition != '')
        $sql .= " Where ".$condition;

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->result_array();
}
/**
 * Retrive all categories from database with tree structure
 * @access public
 * @author Pratik Patel
 * @modified By Rajnish Savaliya
 * @return array()
 */
public function get_all_categories()
{
    $refs = array();
    $list = array();
    $sql = "SELECT iid, cat_code,parent_cat_code, category_name FROM category ";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    while($data = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        $thisref = &$refs[ $data['cat_code'] ];
        $thisref['iid'] = $data['iid'];
        $thisref['cat_code'] = $data['cat_code'];
        //$thisref['parent_cat_code'] = $data['parent_cat_code'];
        $thisref['category_name'] = $data['category_name'];

        if ($data['parent_cat_code'] == 0) {
            $thisref['type'] = 'folder';

            $list[ $data['cat_code'] ] = &$thisref;

        } else {
            $thisref['type'] = 'item';

            $refs[ $data['parent_cat_code'] ]['additionalParameters']['children'][ $data['cat_code'] ] = &$thisref;
        }
    }

    return $list;
}
}
```

**HOW TO USE THIS MODEL**

use is very simple..

Load Model:

```
     $this->load->model("general_model",'general');
```

Set Table to perform operation:

```
     $this->general->set_table('category');
```

set condition

```
   $condition = array();
```

set extra fields like orderby, limit, offset more info you can see in model function 'get()'

```
    $ordersby['parent_tag_id'] = 'desc';
```

Grab the results!!

```
    $results = $this->general->get("id,name",$condition,$ordersby);
```

Comment: Wow thank you Rajnish, I'll take a good look tomorrow and try & study it. Ralph

Comment: if you will get help from it then +1UP :)